# Undo the result of one jQuery event handler when the opposite occurs

Tags: jquery

I just started looking into jQuery yesterday, before this I programmed in only PHP. So the best way I can explain what I'm looking for, is a way to say "else" in jQuery.

Suppose I have the following:

```
$('input').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('fieldBorder');
});
```

How can I say "when the input field is **clicked out of**, then remove the class fieldBorder". I see a lot of ways to do things in jQuery but how does one say the opposite when the user's action has transpired.

Another example:

```
$('a.clickMe').mouseover(function() {
    $('hiddenMessage').show();
});
```

In the above example, is the only way to hide the hidden message once the user has ceased mousing over the link to use something like this:

```
$('a.clickMe').mouseout(function() {
    $('hiddenMessage').hide();
});
```

I get the nagging feeling that there is a much simpler/less redundant way of doing it. Is that what a "call back" is?

### EDIT

From the answers I'm guessing there is no easy way to do it. However I did notice in the ajax function you have this:

```
$.ajax({

type: 'get'
url: 'script.php',
data: 'foo=boo';
success: function() {

alert('it worked');

}, error: function() {

alert('it did not work');

}

})
```

which that `, something else: function()` part existed for all other jQuery code as well.

Comment: I've attempted a better summary title for your question. Please feel free to edit it if what I've guessed at is not really the meat of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not really a jQuery thing, it's about how the browser handles events.

An element can have **focus**. If it can, if can also lose that focus. The event that is fired when an element loses focus is the [`blur` event](http://api.jquery.com/blur/).

Depending on what kind of element you're talking about though, it may never gain focus, even if clicked upon, or it may lose focus at a different time than is convenient for you. In that case you may simply want to listen to when the user `clicks` on the `document` or `<body>`, and determine if you need to do something.

---

AJAX `success` and `error` handlers are not quite the same thing as event handling. At some specific point, an AJAX request either succeeds or fails, it's a one-time `if..else`. Events are more complex though, any event may fire at any time, and there isn't necessarily an "opposite" event. What's the opposite of a `click`? There's no such thing as `unclick`. There's only a `click on a different element`.

There are certain idioms on how to build specific behavior using these constraints. Like, display some element when clicking on a link, and hide the element when clicking on any element that's not the link or the displayed element.

For example, you attach a `click` event handler to the `document`, which will catch *all* click events. For each triggered event, you determine whether its [`target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.target) was some specific element or a child of that element.

For an alternative, you have to understand that events *bubble up*. When you click on some element, the `click` event of that element will be triggered. Then the `click` event of the element's parent will be triggered and so on, until the top element is reached (that's how the `document` catches all events as well).
You can attach an event to the `document` that does something. You also attach a `click` event to some specific element that [stops the event from bubbling up](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/). This way, you have created the effect of "do something when clicking on anything *but* the specific element".

Comment: Hi deceze, can you please show me how I can say that: "when clicking on anything other than the element itself", Like: click() ! $(this) <-- except one that actually works.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the [`mouseup`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseup/) event, although perhaps you want the [`blur`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) event. I'm not sure what "clicked out of" means exactly.

As for `mouseover`/`mouseout`, there is the [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover) event that lets you pair the handlers.

There is no "on the 'opposite' event (whatever that may be) please somehow run the reverse of all the code that I just ran in this handler". It sounds interesting, though! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is another way of doing it. It can be considered as if/else statement in other ways.

```
$("#id").hover(function(e){
                //you can do whatever you want on mouseover here.
    },
        function(){
               //you can do whatever you want on mouse out here.
    });
```

Comment: This doesn't work on the 1st example I posted but does on the second. I guess I will have to write the opposite code myself but I will use this whenever it works. The comma and then "else" function seems more convenient to me.